# Celery SQS tasks will not be executed after failure

Tags: python, celery, amazon-sqs

We are using Celery with SQS broker, the issue is that after task failure another one will not be consumed by the worker where the first was failed

The set up is a single worker with SQS queue, without results backend configured.

While debugging Kombu SQS transport I noticed that `can_consume` method returns false https://github.com/celery/kombu/blob/master/kombu/transport/virtual/base.py#L191

This means that delivered failed messages are not removed

Does anyone have an idea what might cause it?

Answer (score 1):

Created a bugfix PR which will be released on celery==4.4.0

https://github.com/celery/celery/pull/5843